# get value from event in an entrybox

Tags: python-3.x, events, tkinter, listbox, event-handling

#I want to put the  selected item from combobox in the merk_entry. and the selected item from the listbox(omschrijving) in model_entry. 
.get() or insert  aren't working in this function.
I tried both of them. Also Comboboxselected.
I dont know how fix this.

Thanks in advance.

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter.ttk import Combobox
window=Tk()
window.geometry("500x500")

wagenmerk=["BMW","Mercedes","Audi"]
Bmw=["Bmw 1 reeks","Bmw 5 reeks Berline","Bmw 7 reeks"]
Mercedes=["A-klasse","B-klasse","Eqc","C-klasse"]
Audi=["A1","A3","A4"]

def toon_info(evt):
    teller=1
    merk_info=automerk_entry.get()
    print(merk_info)
    if merk_info == "BMW":
        omschrijving.delete(0,END)
        for line in Bmw:
            omschrijving.insert(teller,Bmw[teller-1])
            teller+=1
    elif merk_info=="Mercedes":
        omschrijving.delete(0,END)
        for line in Mercedes:
            omschrijving.insert(teller,Mercedes[teller-1])
            teller+=1
    elif merk_info=="Audi":
        omschrijving.delete(0,END)
        for line in Audi:
            omschrijving.insert(teller,Audi[teller-1])
            teller+=1

automerk_text=Label(text="automerk")
merk_text=Label(text="merk")
model_text=Label(text="model")
prijs_text=Label(text="prijs")


automerk_text.place(x=15,y=70)
merk_text.place(x=280,y=100)
model_text.place(x=280,y=120)
prijs_text.place(x=280,y=140)

merk=StringVar()
model=StringVar()
prijs=StringVar()

merk_entry=Entry(textvariable=merk,width="25")
model_entry=Entry(textvariable=model,width="25")
prijs_entry=Entry(textvariable=prijs,width="25")

merk_entry.place(x=320,y=100)
model_entry.place(x=320,y=125)
prijs_entry.place(x=320,y=150)



automerk_entry=Combobox(window,values=wagenmerk,width=30)
automerk_entry.bind("<<ComboboxSelected>>",toon_info)
automerk_entry.place(x=70,y=70)

omschrijving=Listbox(window,width=30,height=10)
omschrijving.place(x=70,y=100)


#button
bereken=Button(window,text="toon",width="30",height="2",command=toon_info,bg="grey")
bereken.place(x=70,y=270)
```

Comment: What does "aren't working" mean in this context? Does it throw an error? Does it return the wrong information? Something else?

Comment: Have you tried `print(evt)` to see how the event data is structured?

Answer (score 1):

You have not set the two `Entry` widgets to take the change in values. Your `Comboboxselected` works as expected. Do the following changes to reflect the selection of the `Combobox` widget and the `Listbox` widget to the 2 `Entry` widgets:

```
def toon_info(evt):
    teller=1
    merk_info=automerk_entry.get()
    merk.set(merk_info) # set the StringVar variable (assigned to the merk_entry widget)
    ...
    ...
```

Bind the `Listbox` widget:

```
def set_item(evt):
    model.set(omschrijving.get(omschrijving.curselection()[0]))

omschrijving.bind('<<ListboxSelect>>', set_item)
```

And lastly, the Button-`bereken` is not set to send or activate any `event`/`evt`. So the callback function (under the option `command`) has to be changed

Comment: Almost posted a very similar answer. I think he should also set `selectmode=SINGLE` for the listbox because the first selected item would used for setting the Entry

Comment: model.set(omschrijving.get(omschrijving.curselection()[0]))
IndexError: tuple index out of range. that's what I get now.

Comment: @newcoderror try to `print` the contents of `cursorselection()`. You will understand the problem

Answer (score 0):

This is how I fixed it.

```
def set_item(evt):
    model_entry.delete(0,END)
    cur_selection=omschrijving.curselection()
    if len(cur_selection)>0:
      model.set(omschrijving.get(cur_selection[0]))
```